# Selenium WebDriver throws Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

**Test Scenario:** Trying to capture and test Gmail Login.

**Current Output:** Mozilla instance opens up. Username is entered but 
the Password is not being entered by the WebDriver code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ruchi\\workspace2\\SeleniumTest\\jar\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver  varDriver=new FirefoxDriver();

varDriver.get("http://gmail.com");  
WebElement webElem=  varDriver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
webElem.sendKeys("error59878@gmail.com");
WebElement nextButton=varDriver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
nextButton.click();

varDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement wePass=varDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".rFrNMe.P7gl3b.sdJrJc.Tyc9J"));

wePass.sendKeys("test1");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### ElementNotInteractableException

As per the documentation, *ElementNotInteractableException* is the W3C exception which is thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), it is not in a state that can be interacted with.

### Reasons & Solutions :

The reason for *ElementNotInteractableException* to occur can be numerous.

1. Temporary Overlay of other *WebElement* over the *WebElement* of our interest:

   In this case, the direct solution would have been to induce *ExplicitWait* i.e. *WebDriverWait* in combination with `ExpectedCondition` as **`invisibilityOfElementLocated`** as follows:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_element_to_be_invisible")));
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_element_to_be_clicked")).click();
   ```

   A better solution will be to get a bit more granular  and instead of using `ExpectedCondition` as **`invisibilityOfElementLocated`** we can use `ExpectedCondition` as **`elementToBeClickable`** as follows:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   WebElement element1 = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath_of_element_to_be_clicked")));
   element1.click();
   ```
2. Permanent Overlay of other *WebElement* over the *WebElement* of our interest :

   If the overlay is a permanent one in this case we have to cast the **WebDriver** instance as **JavascriptExecutor** and perform the click operation as follows:

   ```
   WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element_xpath"));
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
   ```

---

Now addressing the error **ElementNotInteractableException** in this particular context we need to add **ExplicitWait** i.e. **WebDriverWait** as follows :

You need to induce a bit of *wait* for the *Password* field to be properly rendered in the HTML DOM. You can consider configuring an *ExplicitWait* for it. Here is the working code to login into Gmail using Mozilla Firefox:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Ruchi\\workspace2\\SeleniumTest\\jar\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin";
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
WebElement email_phone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
email_phone.sendKeys("error59878@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password));
password.sendKeys("test1");
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton !! Its working now . If we use classname , I noticed t hat the classname is getting changed.