# Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

After upgrading of Selenium & FF causes org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException error.

```
Selenium 3.4.0
FF 57.0.4
Geckodriver 19.0.1
```

I also tested with latest Chrome driver and it worked fine there as well. But we need to use firefox profiles, so i need this to work there.

My code (where the problem causes):

```html
  public void clickOnUsers(){
    FluentWebElement users = within(secs(10)).link(By.linkText("Users"));
    users.click();
}
```

My console:

```html
org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentExecutionStopped: ElementNotInteractableException during invocation of: ?.within(secs(10)).a(By.linkText: Users).click()
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.Internal$BaseFluentWebDriver.wrapRuntimeException(Internal.java:954)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.Internal$BaseFluentWebDriver.executeAndWrapReThrowIfNeeded(Internal.java:982)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement.executeAndWrapReThrowIfNeeded(FluentWebElement.java:74)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement.click(FluentWebElement.java:79)
at com.ui.test.pages.EditUserPage.clickOnUsers(EditUserPage.java:72)
at com.ui.test.steps.CreateUserSteps.theAdminCreateNewUser(CreateUserSteps.java:99)
at ✽.And the Admin create new User through Organisation(com/ui/test/features/concurrency.feature:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'WS00MU016', ip: '1.1.1.1.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\nat\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.fMAACMYwjGrq, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, moz:headless=false, platform=ANY, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=57.0.4, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=972.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt, moz:webdriverClick=false}]
Session ID: d76dbd71-2270-4698-83e2-edcad4d8f1ba
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement$Click.execute(FluentWebElement.java:1357)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement$Click.execute(FluentWebElement.java:1355)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement$StaleElementRecoveringExecution.doExecution(FluentWebElement.java:1367)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.Internal$BaseFluentWebDriver.executeAndWrapReThrowIfNeeded(Internal.java:976)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement.executeAndWrapReThrowIfNeeded(FluentWebElement.java:74)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.fluent.FluentWebElement.click(FluentWebElement.java:79)
at com.ui.test.pages.EditUserPage.clickOnUsers(EditUserPage.java:72)
at com.ui.test.steps.CreateUserSteps.theAdminCreateNewUser(CreateUserSteps.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver throws "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-elemen)

Comment: None of the proposed solutions is not working in my case