# <Select> Tag is not working for selecting value in dropdown

Tags: selenium, select, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an issue where dropdown has  tag. but still I am unable to select value in dropdown and it is throwing exception. I am able to get dropdown values but unable to select

Here is complete details

URL : https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Testcase: Select multiple values in Skill dropdown.( Find attachment for exact field on web page.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement Dropdown = driver.findElement(By.name("skills"));
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("skills")));
List<WebElement> Options = sel.getOptions();

System.out.println(Options.size());

for(int i=0;i<Options.size()-1;i++) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"example\"]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[8]/div")).click();
    System.out.println(Options.get(i).getAttribute("value"));
    if(Options.get(i).getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("angular")||Options.get(i).getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("Graphic Design")||Options.get(i).getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("HTML")) {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        sel.selectByIndex(i);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Webelement details]

**Exception**:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException:

Please help to suggest for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver throws "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-elemen)

Comment: @DebanjanB i thing wyou have not read my question properly. This is not duplicate at all. I have verified both questions. I am able to select dropdown thorough different way. but I want to know that why is this code not working with <SELECT> class when select tag is given. Here is my code which is working fine.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The dropdown is actually created by the div with the class value containing 'menu transition '. This is the third element below the 'skills' select element. If you right click and inspect any of the options in the dropdown it will show the correct element in the browser console.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thaks for clarification. i tried same later and it worked. But i am only surprise to know that how does SELECT class variable is working for fetching Dropdown value but not for selecting it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The surrounding div around the select tag is used for user interface purposes and maybe other enhanced functionality. You can say that the select tag keeps the data for the divs and also for posting the form data. Also the select tag is not displayed so selenium will not be able to interact with it. The interactions between the divs and select will be managed by javascript. Only way to know accurately whats happening is to look at source code.

Answer (score 2):

Your drop down is a simulated drop down by css, not a HTML native drop down: `Select`. So you can not operate it as native drop down.

After look into the HTML code of your dropdown, there is an embed native drop down, but it's always invisible no matter you expand options or not. Selenium can't operate on invisible element(But you can read value/attribute from it), that's why the exception you met.

Actually all options come from the `div class="menu"`, so you should click the option from `div class="menu"` as below screenshot show:

[image]

Code to resolve your problem:

```
// click arrow down to expand options
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='skills'] + i")).click();
// choose option: Angular
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'multiple')][select[@name='skills']]//div[.='Angular']"));
```

Comment: Awesome buddy!! this was answer which i was expecting