# Selenium/Instagram : send_keys() not working anymore

Tags: python, selenium

I am making an instagram bot in python and it used to work properly until today for some reason. When I pass the username and the password to the send_keys() function, it tells me that the element is not reachable by keyboard. Here's the full error message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 28, in 
>       login_insta(driver, usr, pwd)
>     File "/home/unknown/Documents/code/python/instats/login_profile.py", line 14, in login_insta
>       usr_box.send_keys(username)
>     File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 352, in send_keys
>       'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
>     File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>     File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/home/unknown/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard

This is the function that doesn't work :

```
def login_insta(driver, username, password):
    login = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a")))
    login.click()

    usr_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/label")))
    pwd_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/label")))

    usr_box.send_keys(username)
    pwd_box.send_keys(password)

    login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/span/button")))
    login_button.click()
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver throws "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-elemen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long XPaths like those are very prone to breaking when there are minor changes in the page's code.

Try these XPaths instead:

```
'//input[@type="text"]' // username or phone number
'//input[@type="password"]' // password
'//button[contains(text(), "Log in")]' // log in button
```