# How to automate an analog clock with selenium webdriver and Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, popup

**Context:** I have to automate the time setting with the following rule: The configured time must be 40 minutes longer than the current time.

**Field details:** The field is not editable. When I click on the field, I press an analog clock popup and after I manually select the time, then the field starts showing the selected time (rule: I must have chosen 40 minutes more than the current time)

**Question:** How do I get my automation to take the current time, add 40min and put this value in the field without having to open the popup?

**I tried this, but it didn't work:** driver.findElement(By.name("dateSend")).sendKeys("22/07/2020-17:28");

ERRO: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

***Below are the images of the code and field:***

**Imagem do campo:** não editável
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPy1q.png)

**Código do campo**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7StjS.png)

**Imagem do popup**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XceYX.png)

**Código do popup**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ynv.png)

**Campo 'Disparo' após selecioada a hora:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ewao.png)

**Código do campo com horário**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK9Rv.png)

Answer (score 0):

**ElementNotInteractableException**

Its indicate that even though element is present in DOM but currently its not in state to interact. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-element) SO thread for detail explanation.

**Possible Solution**

Now coming to your question. Use below code to add 40 minutes into current time:

```
String updateTime = "";
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//Adding 40 minute in current time
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 40)

updateTime = timeFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

And then you can try to set value in element as:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("dateSend")).sendKeys("value", updateTime);
```

**OR using javaScript**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("dateSend"));
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+updateTime+"';", element);
```

Also, from attached image, analog clock has 12 hours mode. Try to set value in both AM and PM mode, and then set `SimpleDateFormat` according to that.