# Unable to enter text to input type on Webpage using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Uploaded my entire webpage on which my test is failing here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WHcwpQFi5Cxh1q1MupQEuSPk6CPZs2GC/view?usp=sharing

Below is my Selenium Java code auto-generated by Selenium Recorder IDE Plugin where I'm trying to enter text to input-type on my webpage.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")).sendKeys("Allocation");
```

The above did not work and errors. Hence, I made the below changes to my code:

The below code works intermittently but rarely does it work.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")));
System.out.println("Title of the page is 7.19 -> " + driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")).clear();
System.out.println("Title of the page is 7.20 -> " + driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")).sendKeys("Allocation");
System.out.println("Title of the page is 7.21 -> " + driver.getTitle());
```

I get the below error running my test:

```
Title of the page is 7.18 -> Raise CR Request
Title of the page is 7.19 -> Raise CR Request
Title of the page is 7.20 -> Raise CR Request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.140.15', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Usersxmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:62388}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 5d2f84a25fb9daaaf3c5360a3f6c17e9
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.testSynvmRequest(SynvmRequest.java:301)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.main(SynvmRequest.java:538)
```

Here is the relevant view source code for the text input from the web page:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"></div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"></div></div>

<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12"><div class="form-group col-lg-6 field-crtestrequest-cr_app_name required">

<label class="control-label" for="crtestrequest-cr_app_name">App Name as per AOP</label>

<input type="text" id="crtestrequest-cr_app_name" class="form-control" name="CRTestRequest[cr_app_name]" value="" maxlength="150" aria-required="true">
```

Issue trying @Norayr Sargsyan solution:

```
Title of the page is 7.19 -> Raise CR Request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <label class="control-label" for="crtestrequest-cr_app_name">...</label> is not clickable at point (206, 500). Other element would receive the click: <div class="panel-body" style="margin-top:-21px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.140.15', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Usersxmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63030}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 4791be3194b3fa8635c5b82962202579
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.testSynvmRequest(SynvmRequest.java:301)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.main(SynvmRequest.java:542)
```

Issue trying @Norayr Sargsyan second solution with for loop & `Actions` class

```
Title of the page is 7.19 -> Raise CR Request
Trying to recover from a stale element :stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.140.15', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Usersxmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64331}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 1c190d50b7d77839ad4d4d4452576ad3
Title of the page is 7.19 -> Raise CR Request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input type="text" id="crtestrequest-cr_app_name" class="form-control" name="CRTestRequest[cr_app_name]" value="" maxlength="150" aria-required="true"> is not clickable at point (533, 496). Other element would receive the click: <footer class="main-footer main-content clearfix">...</footer>
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.140.15', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Usersxmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64331}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 1c190d50b7d77839ad4d4d4452576ad3
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.testSynvmRequest(SynvmRequest.java:311)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.main(SynvmRequest.java:576)
```

Issue trying @DebanjanB solution:

```
Title of the page is 7.19 -> Raise CR Request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'myhost', ip: '10.9.140.15', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Usersxmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:63253}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 4699d09a1abe8089612d70509d5047e4
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.testSynvmRequest(SynvmRequest.java:307)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.main(SynvmRequest.java:551)
```

Can you please suggest how can I get it to work?

Comment: You've tried [Class Actions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work... Updated the error from `Actions` class in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying past 24 hours to get this to work and finally did.

Before, I trigger the `Search Assests` button as visible in my video @ 1.11 minutes I tried the below code which worked.

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_code"));
JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
exec.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_code")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_code")).sendKeys("Allocation");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the element which you needed is present on the DOM, but it is not in a state that you can interact with them.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name")));
WebLement input = driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name"))
input.click();
input.clear();
input.sendKeys("123");
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
  try{
     WebLement input = driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name"))
     Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
     actions.moveToElement(input).perform();
     input.click();
     break;
   } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
           System.out.println("Trying to recover from a stale element :" + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still does not work. Updated the Original post with your suggestion's output @Norayr Sargsyan

Comment: @Ashar If you can provide the URL of you test and the element which you want to interact, I will send you the solution

Comment: please find the error updated in my original post trying your suggestion. I can try uploading the whole webpage but this is an internal webpage. Also, copying- pasting the entire view source of the webpage distorts the look and feel but i can try sharing that.

Comment: @Ashar I have updated my answer, check and let me know

Comment: with this change that you suggested i.e `wait.ignoring` i get the same error as stated in the OP for your suggestion. Regarding `Actions` solution how  where did you get `element` in `element.click()`? Could you write the complete solution for `Actions` ?

Comment: Sadly `element is not attached to the page document` error for your other suggestion with `Actions` @Norayr Sargsyan

Comment: Updated my original post with second part error output `Trying to recover from a stale element`

Comment: You should provide the URL of your website, there is a case that you did not mention in question, and I will check it myself

Comment: Sure, i will save and share the webpage as PHP as it is not accessible over the internet. Meanwhile, I have recorded a video demonstrating the problem `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Lk6_SgRkpk` . If you can have a look.

Comment: @ Norayr Sargsyan I shared the entire webpage here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WHcwpQFi5Cxh1q1MupQEuSPk6CPZs2GC/view?usp=sharing 

and youtube link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Lk6_SgRkpk

Comment: @Ashar with your source code it possible to senskey() in input  WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("crtestrequest-cr_app_name"));

        input.sendKeys("anything");

Comment: it does not work either. I guess due to the popup action right before the input issue at 1:11 minutes of the video here https://youtu.be/-Lk6_SgRkpk?t=71    ... could that lead to loss of focus / control on the window or resets the DOM ? if so, what should be the solution in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of invoking *sendKeys()* to the `<label>` you need to invoke on the `<input>` element and ideally to *click()* on the element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.row div.field-crtestrequest-cr_app_name>label[for='crtestrequest-cr_app_name']")));
  element.click();
  element.clear();
  element.sendKeys("Allocation");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='row']//div[contains(@class, 'field-crtestrequest-cr_app_name')]/label[@for='crtestrequest-cr_app_name']")));
  element.click();
  element.clear();
  element.sendKeys("Allocation");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni/46601444#46601444) in:

- [Selenium WebDriver throws Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690971/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-element/44691041#44691041)
- [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard: while sending text to FirstName field in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by/49872160#49872160)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still does not work. Updated the Original post with your suggestion's output @DebanjanB

Comment: @Ashar Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I get a couple of issues compiling your updated suggestion @DebanjanB. 1. element Object is defined twice ... 2. `error: incompatible types: inference variable V has incompatible bounds` . Can you please correct the code as I'm not sure?

Comment: @Ashar Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Does not work @DebanjanB I guess due to the popup action right before the input could be the cause of the issue. Look at 1:11 minutes of the video here youtu.be/-Lk6_SgRkpk?t=71 for the popup actions before I go back to the main window. Is there an option to get focus control back to the main Window ?